# Can't set innerHTML of a div with Html.Action("_TaskDetail", "ProTask")

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In a Click handler I am trying to set the innerHTML of a div(detail_popup) with a MvcHtmlString.

MvcHtmlString Bobo = @Html.Action("_TaskDetail", "ProTask");
Note: _TaskDetail is a partial view.

If I look at Bobo in debug using the HTML visualizer it is perfect.
I then assign innerHTML as such: detail_popup.innerHTML = @Bobo;
This generates a script error ... SCRIPT1002: Syntax error
I am about to lose my gourd! Any help would be much appreciated.
Bob

This is the MvcHtmlString Bobo whose assignment gives me script errors:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Details</title>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font: 12px Nautilus Pompilius;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table#t01 {
        width: 35%;
        background-color: #ffd800;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        11/23/2016 1:08:14 PM

    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Excavate Foundation</td>
            <td>Trench will be 36 inches deep by 25 inches wide</td>
            <td>Robert L. Wells</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Completion</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:00:00</td>
            <td>50%</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Revision DT</th>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Task ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5/29/2016 12:00:00 PM</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>StartDateAct</th>
            <th>StartDateSched</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6/9/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
            <td>6/9/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>FinishDateAct</th>
            <th>FinishDateSched</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6/12/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
            <td>6/12/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>EstIntCost</th>
            <th>EstExtCost</th>
            <th>EstTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>14.00</td>
            <td>34.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ActIntCost</th>
            <th>ActExtCost</th>
            <th>ActTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>BudIntCost</th>
            <th>BudExtCost</th>
            <th>BudTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>14.00</td>
            <td>34.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SurIntCost</th>
            <th>SurExtCost</th>
            <th>SurTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have pulled my hair out

Following is an abbreviated version of my partial view:

```
    @model PromanV3.Models.ProTask

@{
Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Details</title>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font: 12px Nautilus Pompilius;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table#t01 {
        width: 35%;
        background-color: #ffd800;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        @System.DateTime.Now

    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskName)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskDesc)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskOwnerName)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Completion</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Duration)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.CompPercentage)%</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskOptions)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Revision DT</th>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Task ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.RevisionDT)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.ProjectId)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaskId)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The is my div

```
<!-- Begin section that generates the detail popup for the task -->
<div id="DetailBox"
style="display: none;
z-index: 1000;
border: 2px solid blue;
background: yellow;
fill: white;
color: black;
padding-left: 8px;
padding-right: 8px;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-bottom: 3px;
position: absolute;
font: 14px Nautilus Pompilius;
width: 150px;
height: 65px;
">
<script>
@{

ViewBag.vwbProject = 15;
if (ViewBag.vwbTask==null)
{ViewBag.vwbTask = 1;}
}
</script>
</div>
```

This is my click handler:

```
        function setMouseClickmt(xpos, ypos, width, height, message)
    {
        function inner()
        {
            var MultTxtBoxID = this.node.getAttribute("id"); // 'this' refers to the clear_rect (clear rectangle) of the SVG MultTxtBox
            var MultTxtBoxElement = document.getElementById(MultTxtBoxID); // grab the element
            var task_ID = MultTxtBoxElement.getAttribute("id"); 

            var detail_popup = document.getElementById('DetailBox');

            var task_index = getTaskPos(task_ID, arr_of_Tasks);
            detail_popup.setAttribute('data-task',task_index);
            detail_popup.setAttribute('data-project',15);
            var tt = detail_popup.getAttribute('data-task');
            var pp = detail_popup.getAttribute('data-project');

            var ldt = new Date();
            var ldts = ldt.toLocaleString();
            //detail_popup.innerHtml = ldts + '</br>' + tt ;

            @{                    
                MvcHtmlString Bobo = @Html.Action("_TaskDetail", "ProTask");
            };
            detail_popup.innerHTML = @Bobo;

       /* Make the 'DetailBox' div appear */
       detail_popup.style.display = 'block';
       detail_popup.style.top = (100) + 'px';// '400px';//works//mTop + 'px';
       detail_popup.style.left = (1200) + 'px';// //works//mLeft + 'px';
       detail_popup.style.width = 250;//width;
       detail_popup.style.height = 500;//height;
      }
        return inner;
    }
```

This is the script output that it chokes on:

```
                detail_popup.innerHTML = 

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<title>Details</title>
<style>
    table, th, td {
        border: 1px solid black;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        font: 12px Nautilus Pompilius;
    }

    th, td {
        padding: 3px;
        text-align: left;
    }

    table#t01 {
        width: 35%;
        background-color: #ffd800;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
        11/23/2016 1:21:34 PM

    <table id="t01">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Owner</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Excavate Foundation</td>
            <td>Trench will be 36 inches deep by 25 inches wide</td>
            <td>Robert L. Wells</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Duration</th>
            <th>Completion</th>
            <th>Options</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>12:00:00</td>
            <td>50%</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Revision DT</th>
            <th>Project ID</th>
            <th>Task ID</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>5/29/2016 12:00:00 PM</td>
            <td>15</td>
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>StartDateAct</th>
            <th>StartDateSched</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6/9/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
            <td>6/9/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>FinishDateAct</th>
            <th>FinishDateSched</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>6/12/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
            <td>6/12/2016 1:15:00 PM</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>EstIntCost</th>
            <th>EstExtCost</th>
            <th>EstTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>14.00</td>
            <td>34.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>ActIntCost</th>
            <th>ActExtCost</th>
            <th>ActTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>BudIntCost</th>
            <th>BudExtCost</th>
            <th>BudTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20.00</td>
            <td>14.00</td>
            <td>34.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>SurIntCost</th>
            <th>SurExtCost</th>
            <th>SurTotCost</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
            <td>0.00</td>
        </tr>
    </table>


</div>
</body>
</html>
;
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this...
From the razor page, pass the value of Model (@Bobo) to your JS file

```
<script> 
   var tempValue = '@Bobo'; 
   setMouseClickmt(tempValue , yourOtherValues....);
</script>
```

and assign the value passed in your click handler in your JS

```
detail_popup.innerHTML = tempValue ;
```

Add the single quotes around @Bobo when you use it in the script tag of the razor page.
Hope it helps

Comment: I tried the above suggestion and got this new script error   "JavaScript critical error at line 604, column 43 in http://localhost:58251/ProNavView/ProNavFinalView\n\nSCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant"

Comment: My bad... Not sure but maybe you tried it on the external JS file? If so, try to pass the model (@Bobo) to your click handler (JS file from the Razor page by adding a <script> var tempValue = '@Bobo"; setMouseClickmt(tempValue ,......);</script> tag.